How do I connect config.toml to my app? Or does it not work?
I made a config.toml inside of .streamlit. These are the file paths:

The file path shortened down:
Source_Code
├─ __pycache__
├─ .streamlit
│  └─ config.toml
├─ atc_1.py
└─ runner.py

But it won't work. Is config.toml already connected, or should I manually do this?
I had tried to keep the .streamlit file outside of all the other files, but it won't work. right now, the code in config.toml was meant to be a placeholder, and it works only if the all the text switches to a serif font.

To connect a config.toml file to your Streamlit app, you can use the toml library to read the configuration and then use it within your Streamlit app.
Read the config.toml file in your Streamlit app:
Use the toml library to load the configuration file.
Use the configuration in your Streamlit app:
Access the configuration settings and use them to customize your app.
This is my basic understanding of your problem.I hope it helps.
